# GParted merge unallocated space to ext4 partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, ext4

[image]

Here I want to merge unallocated space to ext4 partition. But during running in Ubuntu it is not allowed. Am I right? It has key picture. I must do that Ubuntu DVD booting from it and selecting try Ubuntu there with GParted, I must merge this unallocated part by right clicking on ext4 partition and then selecting shrink. Am I right?

Then for swap area I want to take 5GB from extended partition (which is now called D on Windows). Can I format this partition in Windows or should I use GParted? But in GParted it has key picture. Or in the same way should I do this during trying Ubuntu to merge unallocated space to ext4? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I have no idea what the text means in the screenshot. Why don't you run Ubuntu in English? Yes you need to be running a live session (USB/DVD) to edit your partitions. Not sure what you want to do, can you rewrite yoyr text please? Right now it's very unclear.

Comment: Ok Sorry for my writing. I want to merge 37.52GiB unallocated part to my ubuntu which is ext4.And I want to take 5GiB from extended part for swap area.

Comment: user255742 [check my edits](http://askubuntu.com/a/435407/212123) regarding a swap partition creation.

Comment: In Turkish, ayrilmamis = "unallocated", yeni birim = "new partition"

Answer (score 11):

The steps:

1. Start GParted in live Ubuntu session,
2. Unmount (if it's mounted) the partition that will be involved in the resize/move operation, here `/dev/sda2` (by right clicking and selecting unmount from the context menu),
3. Now *right click* your `/dev/sda2` partition and select **`Resize/Move`** option, and **drag the slider right** to cover the entire unallocated space. And then click the <kbd>Resize/Move</kbd> button,
   [image: snap1]
4. After specifying the resize options, from the menu select **`Edit -> Apply All Operations`** or click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button in the toolbar. Wait patiently for the operation to complete.

Comment: The smudging was unnecessary.

Comment: Does not work for ubuntu 14.04 and gparted 0.18.0 - maximum and minimum size equals current size

Answer (score 1):

You can boot from Ubuntu's LiveCD and use GParted on it or download GParted's LiveCD .iso, burn it to a CD and boot into it. The key icon beside a partition means that said partition is mounted and thus cannot be modified. Booting to a LiveCD should resolve this issue. If it does not, use `umount` to unmount a partition.

Since the unallocated space is to the left of the ext4 partition you wish to resize, you'll first need to move the partition to the left of the unallocated space, which might cause boot error. Follow [GParted's instructions on moving partitions](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-move-partition).

Then right-click on the ext4 partition and select "resize". Expanding it will shrink the unallocated space and expand the partition's free space. Leave 5GB unallocated and use it to create a swap area.

Comment: should I format unallocated part to ext4 before emereging or resizing sda2 will do it for me ? and unallocated part is the right of ext4 , should I slide to the right