# How to completely remove windows 8 from laptop

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-8, 15.04, format

I am currently using Ubuntu 15.04 in my Lenovo ideapad Z510 which was preinstalled with Windows 8.1. Once I shifted to linux, I decided to dual-boot it with windows 8.1 temporarily. So later when I had no use of windows, I used `GParted` to format the windows partition.

Windows was initially installed in `/dev/sda4` partition. As you can see it has *1.14GiB* of used space even after the format. This is also supported by the fact that the windows boot option in grub takes me to windows recovery.

I want to know, is there is a way to completely get rid of this? So that I can use all of the *61.43GiB*.

[image]

Also, in the above picture `/dev/sda` is shown to be *931.51GiB* (top right corner). But actually my disk capacity is *1TB*. What happened to the remaining storage? Is it the BIOS? If not, is there any way I can access it?

Answer (score 1):

what you see is value in GiB and not in GB

look here: http://wintelguy.com/gb2gib.html

931.3225746154785 GiB = 1000 GB

1TB (terabyte) = 0.90949470177293 TiB (tebibyte) = 931 GiB 330 MiB 324 KiB

**So the answer is, your HDD has the full capacity it's supposed to.**

Also merging those circa 60 GiB to some of yours partitions is possible, but in your current setup not very safe, moving, stretching would be neccessary and it can go wrong.

**Answer to your first question is here**: [New ext4 partition and used space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131516/new-ext4-partition-and-used-space)

Comment: I'm fine with the 2% overhead. What about the windows recovery after grub? Can't I remove that?

Comment: `\dev\sda2` I suppose ? Yes you can merge, but now you have `/tmp` on that partition, so I have really no idea if it would be created elsewhere on it's own. http://askubuntu.com/questions/435655/gparted-merge-unallocated-space-to-ext4-partition - you would have to delete this partition.

Comment: here they talk about moving mount points: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8988/how-to-change-mount-points

Comment: My comments are all based on fact, that windows recovery partition has 100 MB, so I guessed it will be `\dev\sda2`, but it might be `sda6` correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I am getting `/tmp` disk full messages all the time. So you might be correct. `sudo apt-get clean` didn't work. I was thinking of asking a seperate question for that.

Comment: I have asked another question. Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/637861/remove-windows-recovery-in-tmp-apt-get-clean-doesnt-work).

Answer (score 0):

While the disk capacity is 1TB, the actual formatted capacity will be 931.51GB. This is because of the difference between how the OS counts the size, and how the HDD manufacturer counts it. Hardware manufacturers use what's known as a 'decimal byte', which means that they use powers of 10 in calculating size. OSes determine the size using a 'binary byte' instead. It basically means that there's a discrepancy in how it's counted. For more information, check out the following link [here.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/gigabyte-decimal-vs-binary/)